# Interactively changing a python code?

Tags: python, scripting

is it possible to iterate through a python code ? 
For example I need to do these ops

```
bpy.ops.example_01()
bpy.ops.another_example_01()
bpy.ops.third_example_01()
bpy.ops.ect_example_01()
bpy.ops.yet_another_01()
```

For number 01 to 20 for each end of operations  . A

Instead of creating a definition that replace every end of the operation is it possible to replace only the number 01 by 02,03,04.. ?  I know the exec(« text ») trick, but this isn’t what I’m looking for, don’t work for what I’m doing.

Comment: Are you looking to pass a property to an operator and inside do different things based on the property? Else I am not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Suggest this is basic python `getattr`